# Unable to publish Current User fields

Tags: jquery, meteor

I have turned off auto publish in my App and am trying to Publish User Data that is submitted after user is creates. Following is my Publishing code on server side ...

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
  if (this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
                             {fields: {'services':1, 'firstLogin':0, 'verified':1, 'skills':1, 'role':1}});
  } else {
    this.ready();
  }
});
```

And following is my Subscription code.

```
Meteor.subscribe("userData");
```

But all I see are _id, firstLogin, services and profile. I can see rest of the fields when i do db.users.find() but I can access them in browser console.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you referencing the fields properly (are the elements at the top-level inside the object or are they inside another element)?  Can you show the output from the mongo console when you do `db.users.find({_id:"THE_ID_YOU_ARE_LOOKING_UP"});`?

Comment: db.users.find()
{ 
"_id" : "---", 
"createdAt" : ---,  
"firstLogin" : 0, 

"profile" : { "name" : "Gagan Deep", "firstName" : "Gagan", "lastName" : "Deep", "dob" : ISODate("1986-12-12T18:30:00Z"), "gender" : "male", "suburb" : "BRS Nagar", "city" : "Ludhiana", "state" : "Punjab", "postcode" : "141001", "country" : "India", "relocateLocal" : "1", "relocateInternational" : "1" }, 

"skills" : [ "HTML", "PHP", "Meteor" ], 
"verified" : 0, 
"role" : "user" 
}

This is the data I get for the user on the db search. The verified and skills fields I'm trying to publish are top-level.

Comment: When I try your publish function I get an error: `Exception from sub userData id ___ MinimongoError: You cannot currently mix including and excluding fields.`  If you want firstLogin included change the 0 to a 1.  Otherwise remove it from the fields list.  Then refresh your page and see if your fields are there in the web console.

Comment: Mark is right, you can't mix include and exclude fields.

Answer (score 0):

From the mongo documentation (http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/):

> You cannot combine inclusion and exclusion semantics in a single
>   projection with the exception of the _id field.

If you want `firstLogin` included change the 0 to a 1. Otherwise remove it from the fields list.